# Правильная таблица связей SQL

Tags: php, sql

Делаю CRM-систему, необходимо добавить задачи, чтобы их можно было связывать со сделкой, клиентом, заявкой и т.д. Как правильно это сделать?

В БД на данный момент есть таблица `clients`, `sales`, `leads`.
Из понятного: таблица `tasks` содержит в себе поля `id, title, text, add_date, task_date`. Как сделать связь между клиентом/продажей/лидом и задачей?

Думал сделать промежуточную таблицу `tasks_has_entities (id, task_id, entity, entity_id)`, где `entity` - это название сущности `(clients, sales, leads)`, а `entity_id` - это id строки в таблице `entity`.

Но вопрос - как правильно построить запрос? Уже пробовал просто написать, но не понимаю. Это же нужно делать циклом, правильно понимаю? Чтобы вытаскивать данные по каждой сущности

Comment: Либо, как вы сказали, через промежуточную таблицу, или же для каждой сущности свою отдельную таблицу задач. По поводу как писать запросы - просто поставлять нужный entity_id в запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой вариант выбрать связанные данные по задаче:

```
select * from tasks
left join task_entity on task_id = tasks.id
left join clients on entity = 'client' and entity_id = clients.id
left join sales on entity = 'sales' and entity_id = sales.id
left join leads on entity = 'leads' and entity_id = leads.id
```